# Рандом перестал быть случайным

Tags: php, netbeans, случайные-числа

Здравствуйте, друзья! Пишу генератор фейковых личностей, проблемы начинаются даже в таком малюсеньком куске кода - данные начитают дублироваться через равные промежутки. Если вывод длиннее - "Фамилия Имя Отчество Адрес Телефон и т.д.", то повторяющиеся строки результата идут каждые 30 строк. Когда вывожу только фамилии и индексы - каждые 100 строк. Нет, я верю что рандомизатор может выдёргивать из архива фамилий одну и ту же фамилию периодически, но чтобы он делал это каждые 100 строк и к ней генерировал один и тот же шестизначный индекс - увольте, у меня идеи кончились.

Грузил тот же скрипт на хостинг, там пообновлял страничку - вроде дубликатов не заметил. Пишу в NetBeans 8.0.2, вывод на локалхост.

```
//Хватаем случайную фамилию
$famtxt = file('surname.txt');
$surname = $famtxt[ array_rand($famtxt) ]; 
unset($famtxt); 

//Общий вывод
$result0=$surname.' '.rand(100000, 999999);                               
$resulttxt = fopen('result2.txt', 'a');
fwrite($resulttxt,$result0);
```

Comment: Проблема возникает при выполнении PHP-кода на винде?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ситуацию вы описали, но забыли задать вопрос.

Если вас интересует причина, то проблема абсолютно точно в вашем ПО, скорее всего с интерпретатором php. Если точнее, то с генератором псевдослучайных чисел. Код вы написали рабочий. Ради интереса забил документ болванками и проверил.

Если вам интересны способы исправления данной проблемы, то попробуйте начать с банального перезагрузить -> переустановить -> обратиться в поддержку разработчика ПО. Можно попытать счастья с функцией [srand()](http://www.php.su/functions/?srand) (хотя это вряд ли).

Если же вас интересуют варианты обхода, то вы можете установить другой программный продукт или продолжить написание скрипта непосредственно на хостинге.

Comment: Спасибо! 
На хостинге взлетело отлично. 
Вопрос был в общем-то откуда лезет проблема с зацикливающимися результатами. Какие-то подозрения были на генератор псевдослучайных чисел, но затем решил что таких откровенных дыр в средах разработки не бывает. 
Бывают, оказалось.

Comment: Для уменьшения шанса повтора,  я бы добавил переменную вес для каждого значения, увеличивающуюся при каждом использовании значения. Кода будет больше, но уникальность результата выше. И так же можно будет управлять частотой использования значений ( к примеру надо чаще использовать имя Иван, и реже отчество Петрович. Выставив изначально вес ниже для Ивана и выше для Петровича).